# How can I send a file with DLL to Cuckoo Sandbox?

Tags: windows, malware, sandbox

I want to submit an executable for analysis in Cuckoo Sandbox.

The file must be in the same folder with a DLL I have. How can I request Cuckoo to test my exe and make it run properly? (i.e exe and dll in the same directory).

Note - I don't have any problem to put the dll at the guest machine, take a snapshot and then submit the file. I just don't know where to put my dll in the guest machine (Where Cuckoo put the exe on guest?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuckoo creates a folder with a randomly generated name (So it changes every time you run a new analysis) in the root of C:\ which it uses to store the submitted file, among other things.

What you could probably do is create a zip file containing both your executable and your DLL file, then submit that zip to Cuckoo. When the analysis is run Cuckoo's zip package will unzip the archive containing both files into the same directory, then run the first executable it finds from that zip.

I think that should do the trick.